# Add field to Devise user registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use Devise with my Ruby on Rails 4 application for user authentication/registration. I want to add one more field to my user registration form called `nickname`. Adding this field to the views is straight forward, but what's the best way to go ahead and ensure that Devise ensures that it persists to the model and doesn't reject this attribute as it is non-standard for it is built for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is rejecting the attribute then i suppose you need to add this to the application controller.

```
 def configure_permitted_parameters

        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:nickname) }
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:nickname, :email, :password) }
      end
```

I hope you are talking about this.

Comment: I'm guessing that means I need to create a new registrations controller and route registrations to it, in order for this to work?

Comment: No. you can just add it to your application_controller.rb